# MouseEventArgs inheritance to ScrollEventArgs

Tags: c#, inheritance, scrollbar, mouseevent, mousewheel

I am trying to move a VScrollBar with a mouse, VScrollBar is handling the below, I thought I could take this method to `this.ctlVScroll.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(ctlVScroll_Scroll);` but I could not. Because, MouseEventHandler takes MouseEventArgs into itself. But ctlVScroll_Scroll uses ScrollEventArgs. Is there any way that I can use ctlVScroll_Scroll into MouseEventHandler? Here is my codes parts below:

```
this.ctlVScroll.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(ctlVScroll_Scroll);
        this.ctlVScroll.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(ctlVScroll_Scroll/*here it does not accept*/);


private void ctlHScroll_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int i = ctlHScroll.Value;
            int j = 0;
            int k = Columns.GetTotalWidth();

            j = i;

            switch (e.Type)
            {
                case ScrollEventType.First:
                    i = 0;
                    break;
                case ScrollEventType.Last:
                    i = k - 1;
                    break;
                case ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement:
                    if (i - ctlHScroll.SmallChange > 0)
                    {
                        i -= ctlHScroll.SmallChange;
                        if (i < 0)
                            i = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement:
                    if (i + ctlHScroll.SmallChange < k - 1)
                    {
                        i += ctlHScroll.SmallChange;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i = k - 1;
                    }
                    break;...
}
```

If anything you don't get, I can add or edit question.
Thanks for your help.

Best Regards.

Comment: A scrollbar already knows how to handle MouseWheel messages.  You can see the [code here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ScrollBar.cs,e8dff45ebd77c3ec).  Why you have to help is very unclear.   Just override the OnMouseWheel() method if you want it to do something else.

Comment: nope, my scrollbar does not take the mousewheel messages. Thats the problem.

Comment: The message is sent to the window with the focus.  Click on the scrollbar first, then use the wheel.

Comment: I click the window as usual but it does not use mousewheel. I am using TabControl. In the first 2 tabs I can use the mousewheel control, but for 3rd,4th,5th tabs I can not. Do you have any guess about that? If you want, I can share the both tabs' codes, but they are really long codes.

Comment: The scrollbar, not "the window".  You have an obvious need for providing us with a minimum repro, we can't help you with that.